# Changing WordPress sort order for returned child pages

Tags: custom-post-types, query, loop, order

I have a custom `WP_Query` that looks like this:

```
$this_page_id=$wp_query->post->ID; 
 $images = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'menu-item', 'post_parent' => $this_page_id ) );
```

My problem is that when using the `orderby` parameter (see here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) to sort by `menu_order` (which I need to do for the project). The sort order is not working.

I'm 99% certain the reason it's not working is because I'm directing it to query all children of a specific post and the `orderby` parameter doesn't "dig that deep into the query" if that makes sense to anyone.

Can anyone offer some help?  doing this (the expected solution yields nothing):

```
$this_page_id=$wp_query->post->ID; 
     $images = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'menu-item', 'post_parent' => $this_page_id, 'orderby' => 'menu_order' ) );
```

Comment: try adding 'order' => 'ASC' and see if anything changes...

Comment: So funny!  I had tried that before but had a separate error which I later found and then forgot to go back and re-add `order => ASC`. Thanks!

Comment: Add it as an answer if you want the reputation, your answer was correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should work.

```
$images = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'menu-item', 'post_parent' => $this_page_id, 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC' ) );
```